# Why is my PE file invalid?

Tags: winapi, linker, portable-executable, coff

I already asked a similar question, ["PE Header requirements"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082264/pe-header-requirements), but I'm not really satisfied with it's answer.

I am building an assembler/linker, in Java SE 1.6. I have read about 5 different documentations/specifications about the PE/COFF header and file format, but I'm stuck at a problem:

My generated file is not valid, says Windows: **"X is not a valid Win32 application."** I'm clueless of what can be wrong; I have double-checked every entry in the PE Header and PE Optional Header, and all seems to be right.
I've got three sections:

- `code` (RVA `0x1000`, File `0x400`)
- `data` (RVA `0x2000`, File `0x600`)
- `import` (RVA `0x3000`, File `0x800`)

My entrypoint value is at `0x1000` (the beginning of `code`) and my imagebase is `0x400000`. Section alignment is `0x1000` and file alignment is `0x200`.

**See the revisions of this question to see the whole file.**

So: I grabbed a valid PE file (a simple "Hello World" message box application), and started to modify it, with a hex-editor (HxD). I got a lot of different error messages, *not* the "X is not a valid Win32 application.":

I'm aware that my `code` content is not "valid" code, but I've tested it out: invalid code gives an Application Crash error.

If the import-section content is invalid in the "Hello World" PE file, it gives me the error "Procedure point cannot be found in [...]", or "Application has failed to start because [..] dll is not found.", or an Application Crash. These errors are all very useful; they all give me some clue what was wrong.

But my PE file, with the error "X is not a valid Win32 application.", drives me insane: *What is wrong with my PE file?*

*Dumpbin output:*

```
E:\Documenten\CP Language\compiler\Win32Builder>dumpbin /ALL test.exe
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.21003.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Dump of file test.exe
PE signature found
File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE
FILE HEADER VALUES
         14C machine (x86)
           3 number of sections
    32EB4BF5 time date stamp Sun Jan 26 13:20:05 1997
           0 file pointer to symbol table
           0 number of symbols
          E0 size of optional header
         703 characteristics
               Relocations stripped
               Executable
               32 bit word machine
               Debug information stripped
               CD - run from swapfile

OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES
         10B magic # (PE32)
        8.00 linker version
        1000 size of code
        1000 size of initialized data
           0 size of uninitialized data
        1000 entry point (00401000)
        1000 base of code
        2000 base of data
      400000 image base (00400000 to 0040088F)
        1000 section alignment
         200 file alignment
        4.00 operating system version
       13.37 image version
        4.00 subsystem version
           0 Win32 version
         890 size of image
         400 size of headers
           0 checksum
           2 subsystem (Windows GUI)
           0 DLL characteristics
       40000 size of stack reserve
       11000 size of stack commit
      100000 size of heap reserve
        1000 size of heap commit
           0 loader flags
          10 number of directories
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of Export Directory
        3000 [    1000] RVA [size] of Import Directory
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of Resource Directory
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of Exception Directory
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of Certificates Directory
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of Base Relocation Directory
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of Debug Directory
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of Architecture Directory
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of Global Pointer Directory
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of Thread Storage Directory
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of Load Configuration Directory
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of Bound Import Directory
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of Import Address Table Directory
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of Delay Import Directory
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of COM Descriptor Directory
           0 [       0] RVA [size] of Reserved Directory

SECTION HEADER #1
   .code name
    1000 virtual size
    1000 virtual address (00401000 to 00401FFF)
      23 size of raw data
     400 file pointer to raw data (00000400 to 00000422)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
60000020 flags
         Code
         Execute Read    
RAW DATA #1
  00401000: 68 00 00 00 00 68 0D 20 40 00 68 00 20 40 00 68  h....h. @.h. @.h
  00401010: 00 00 00 00 E8 64 30 40 00 68 00 00 00 00 E8 6C  ....èd0@.h....èl
  00401020: 30 40 00                                         0@.

SECTION HEADER #2
   .data name
    1000 virtual size
    2000 virtual address (00402000 to 00402FFF)
      23 size of raw data
     600 file pointer to raw data (00000600 to 00000622)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
C0000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Read Write
RAW DATA #2
  00402000: 48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 57 6F 72 6C 64 21 00 48 65 6C  Hello World!.Hel
  00402010: 6C 6F 20 53 74 61 63 6B 20 4F 76 65 72 66 6C 6F  lo Stack Overflo
  00402020: 77 21 00                                         w!.

SECTION HEADER #3
 .import name
    1000 virtual size
    3000 virtual address (00403000 to 00403FFF)
      90 size of raw data
     800 file pointer to raw data (00000800 to 0000088F)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
50000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Shared
         Read Only
RAW DATA #3
  00403000: 54 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3C 30 00 00  T0..........<0..
  00403010: 64 30 00 00 5C 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  d0..\0..........
  00403020: 47 30 00 00 6C 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  G0..l0..........
  00403030: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 75 73 65 72  ............user
  00403040: 33 32 2E 64 6C 6C 00 6B 65 72 6E 65 6C 33 32 2E  32.dll.kernel32.
  00403050: 64 6C 6C 00 74 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 82 30 00 00  dll.t0.......0..
  00403060: 00 00 00 00 74 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 82 30 00 00  ....t0.......0..
  00403070: 00 00 00 00 00 00 4D 65 73 73 61 67 65 42 6F 78  ......MessageBox
  00403080: 41 00 00 00 45 78 69 74 50 72 6F 63 65 73 73 00  A...ExitProcess.

  Section contains the following imports:

user32.dll
            403064 Import Address Table
            403054 Import Name Table
                 0 time date stamp
                 0 Index of first forwarder reference

                0 MessageBoxA

kernel32.dll
            40306C Import Address Table
            40305C Import Name Table
                 0 time date stamp
                 0 Index of first forwarder reference

                0 ExitProcess

Summary
    1000 .code
    1000 .data
    1000 .import
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Size Of Image is, according to dumpbin `890`, while it should be the size of image in the memory, i.e. the latest section's RVA + that section's rounded-up size (e.g. `0x5000` in this case).

It works. Thanks for anserws, especially the hint to `dumpbin`!

Answer (score 4):

You are definitely tackling this problem from the wrong end.  Hacking the hex isn't ever going to get you what you want, the PE file structure is too sophisticated.  You'll need two things.

- Matt Pietrek's [seminal article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx) is essential reading to understand the structure.  Don't get started on code until you understand at least 75% of it.
- You'll need the Windows SDK.  The include/winnt.h file contains the declarations of the structures used in the PE format.  It starts at _IMAGE_DOS_HEADER, the first chunk of the file.

Write the code to create the structures from their declarations, that's the only way to end up with a valid executable file.

PS: your hex dumps hang up the browsers of anybody that tries to look at your question.

Comment: Thanks. I've read a lot about the PE header, I understand a lot of it. I can't use the Windows SDK: because I program in Java, which can't use the C-header files.
I'm hacking with a HEX editor, because I don't know why my structures I use in Java are wrong.
About the browser-hang; how can anybody help me with my problem if they don't have my PE file?

Comment: You can copy the structure declarations and make them compatible with whatever language you're comfortable with.  They are not that big.  Make sure you did it right by first writing code that *reads* an EXE.  If you google the member names, it is likely you'll find code of somebody that already did this.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google revealed:

http://rcecafe.net/?p=26. No one here is going to grovel through your bytes for you, the best you can expect is pointers to tools.