# Which of the MS-DOS header fields are mandatory/optional?

Tags: portable-executable

[image]

The above is the complete list of MS-DOS header fields, but I don't know which of them are mandatory and which are optional, does anyone know?

Comment: Can I suggest not 'childing' this up and using MS-DOS?  (Oh yeah, and accept some answers too)

Comment: You do know DOS stub exists in every PE today,don't U?

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to create PE Image, `e_magic`(Magic number) and `elfanew`(File address of new exe header) are the only mandatory fields that you have to fill in. `elfanew` should point to the PE `IMAGE_NT_HEADER` structure.

Answer (score 3):

Well back in 2006 someone wanted to create the world most tiny PE. For this he wrote a small PE Fuzzer. With the smallest codebase posible.

```
return 42;
```

He managed to get the following sizes of PE's
you are too busy to read the entire page, here is a summary of the results:

- Smallest possible PE file: **97 bytes**
- Smallest possible PE file on Windows 2000: **133 bytes**
- Smallest PE file that downloads a file over WebDAV and executes it: **133 bytes**

You can check his work here:
http://www.phreedom.org/research/tinype/

He also states the required header values. These are:

- e_magic
- e_lfanew
- Machine
- NumberOfSections
- SizeOfOptionalHeader
- Characteristics

**OptionalHeader:**

- Magic
- AddressOfEntryPoint
- ImageBase
- SectionAlignment
- FileAlignment
- MajorSubsystemVersion
- SizeOfImage
- SizeOfHeaders
- Subsystem
- SizeOfStackCommit
- SizeOfHeapReserve

Answer (score 0):

For MS-DOS, all of the headers are mandatory.

For Win9x and above, e_lfanew must be the offset from the start of the image to the start of the IMAGE_NT_HEADERS, and e_magic must be IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE ('MZ').